# How do you change the Order an OrderItem is associated with in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

An `Order` `has_many` `OrderItems`. So `OrderItem` has an `order_id` field.

How do you change which `Order` an `OrderItem` belongs to? Such that you can call `@order.order_items`.

I tried changing the `order_id` of `OrderItem`, but it isn't working. Or at least it isn't showing up when I call `@order.order_items`.

**Edit: Console**

```
~/practice/dinner_dash >>  rails c --sandbox
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 4.0.3)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit
2.0.0-p451 :001 > order1 = Order.first
  Order Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" ORDER BY "orders"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<Order id: 2, status: "Unsubmitted.", user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-06-28 16:21:24", updated_at: "2014-06-28 16:21:24"> 
2.0.0-p451 :002 > order1.order_items.each { |order_item| puts order_item }
  OrderItem Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = ?  [["order_id", 2]]
#<OrderItem:0x007f9dd34d0710>
#<OrderItem:0x007f9dd35b9550>
#<OrderItem:0x007f9dd35b8fd8>
 => [#<OrderItem id: 8, quantity: 5, item_id: 2, order_id: 2, created_at: "2014-06-28 16:30:33", updated_at: "2014-06-29 02:06:17">, #<OrderItem id: 9, quantity: 2, item_id: 3, order_id: 2, created_at: "2014-06-28 16:30:45", updated_at: "2014-06-28 16:56:41">, #<OrderItem id: 15, quantity: 1, item_id: 4, order_id: 2, created_at: "2014-06-28 17:42:17", updated_at: "2014-06-28 17:42:17">] 
2.0.0-p451 :003 > order2 = Order.last
  Order Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" ORDER BY "orders"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Order id: 15, status: "Unsubmitted.", user_id: 2, created_at: "2014-06-28 17:38:08", updated_at: "2014-06-28 17:40:11"> 
2.0.0-p451 :004 > order2.order_items.first.order = order1
  OrderItem Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = ? ORDER BY "order_items"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["order_id", 15]]
 => #<Order id: 2, status: "Unsubmitted.", user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-06-28 16:21:24", updated_at: "2014-06-28 16:21:24"> 
2.0.0-p451 :005 > order1.order_items.each { |order_item| puts order_item }
#<OrderItem:0x007f9dd34d0710>
#<OrderItem:0x007f9dd35b9550>
#<OrderItem:0x007f9dd35b8fd8>
 => [#<OrderItem id: 8, quantity: 5, item_id: 2, order_id: 2, created_at: "2014-06-28 16:30:33", updated_at: "2014-06-29 02:06:17">, #<OrderItem id: 9, quantity: 2, item_id: 3, order_id: 2, created_at: "2014-06-28 16:30:45", updated_at: "2014-06-28 16:56:41">, #<OrderItem id: 15, quantity: 1, item_id: 4, order_id: 2, created_at: "2014-06-28 17:42:17", updated_at: "2014-06-28 17:42:17">] 
2.0.0-p451 :006 >
```

**Edit: Real problem**

I think the real problem is that the `@order` returned by `load_order` is being cached. So the second time `load_order` is called, it's returning the old `@order` that was cached in memory. I'm not sure how to fix it though.

**application_controller.rb**

```
def load_order
    @order = Order.find_or_initialize_by_id(session[:order_id], status: 'Unsubmitted.', user_id: session[:user_id])
    if @order.new_record?
        @order.save!
        session[:order_id] = @order.id
    end
  end
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
def create
        user = login(params[:email], params[:password], params[:remember_me])
        if user
            load_order
            @order.update(user_id: user.id)
            merge_orders
            session[:order_id] = Order.find_by_user_id(user.id).id if Order.find_by_user_id(user.id)
            load_order
            redirect_back_or_to root_path, notice: 'Logged in!'
        else
            flash.now.alert = 'Email or password was invalid.'
            render :new
        end
    end
```

**Edit: Code that isn't working**

The `order_items` that are printed out each time are the same. However, `order_item.order_id` is being changed.

```
def merge_orders
    orders = Order.all
    user_orders = {}
    orders.each do |order|
        if user_orders[order.user_id] == nil
            user_orders[order.user_id] = order
        else
            original_order = user_orders[order.user_id]

            original_order.order_items.each do |order_item|
                item = Item.find_by_id(order_item.item_id)
                puts "\n\n\n#{item.name} x #{order_item.quantity}\n\n\n"
            end

            current_order = order
            # assign order_id of current_order to original_order
            current_order.order_items.each do |order_item|
                puts "order_item.order_id: #{order_item.order_id}"
                order_item.update(order_id: original_order.id)
                puts "order_item.order_id: #{order_item.order_id}"
            end

            original_order.order_items.each do |order_item|
                item = Item.find_by_id(order_item.item_id)
                puts "\n\n\n#{item.name} x #{order_item.quantity}\n\n\n"
            end

            # delete current_order
            current_order.destroy
            puts "\n\n\n"
        end
    end
  end
```

**order.rb**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy

  validates_associated :order_items
end
```

**order_item.rb**

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :order

  validates_presence_of :order_id, :item_id, :quantity
  validates :quantity, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
end
```

Comment: Show you models and code that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order_id of the OrderItem, and saving it should work. You can also do this:

```
order_item.order = a_different_order
```

Because that data can be cached in memory, to see this effect on the original order you may have to do:

```
original_order.reload.order_items
```

You can also verify the other other way by doing:

```
order_item.reload.order
```

ps. You should also check out the awesome_print gem to print this to the console.

pps. You should be doing this in a test :)

Here's an example from my console where Answer belongs_to User

```
1.8.7-p352 :003 > a = Answer.last
1.8.7-p352 :005 > a.user_id
 => 4212 
1.8.7-p352 :006 > old_user = a.user
1.8.7-p352 :007 > a.user = User.last
1.8.7-p352 :008 > a.user_id
 => 7290 
1.8.7-p352 :009 > a.user = old_user
1.8.7-p352 :010 > a.user_id
 => 4212 
1.8.7-p352 :016 > a.changed?
 => true 
1.8.7-p352 :017 > a.save
  SQL (7.1ms)  BEGIN
  AREL (5.1ms)  UPDATE `answers` SET `updated_at` = '2014-06-29 17:39:30', `user_id` = 7290 WHERE `answers`.`id` = 21
  SQL (0.4ms)  COMMIT
 => true 
1.8.7-p352 :018 > a.changed?
 => false
```

\

Comment: From what I understand, calling `update` should save it. Is that true? `original_order.reload.order_items` is printing out the right things now, but it still isn't working in my app (When I log in, it isn't showing that the order is updated).

Comment: I think I figured out the problem, but don't know how to fix it. See the edit to the question.

Comment: So what I gather from that is that I should do `order_item.order = original_order` instead of `order_item.update(order_id: original_order.id)`. But that doesn't work. Calling `original_order.reload.order_items` afterwards doesn't do anything either.

Comment: The two methods above are equivalent. You need to simplify your situation to find out what you're doing wrong. I don't the way you're handling the field change is the problem. Do it in the console and post your code like I've done.

Comment: Ps, you'll need to save your model obviously. Added that bit above.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working in the console either. See the edit to the question.

Comment: First of all, you need to learn to simplify problems to get to the most minimal situation where things aren't working. Iterating over things in this case is just complicating what may not be working. Second of all you didn't save the order_item once you changed the order like I showed you in my example. Try this order_item = OrderItem.first; order_item.order_id; order_item.order = Order.last; order_item.save; order_item.order_id;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56490/discussion-between-adam-zerner-and-pixelearth).

Answer (score 0):

> How do you change which Order an OrderItem belongs to?

The simplest explanation is to change the `order_id` of that record. There is simply no other way, unless, of course, you've got multiple records associated to an `order`

--

**Merge**

I think your problem is to do with your `merge` functionality

I don't understand what you're doing with this  - it seems like you're outputting `item` x `quantity` or something - if you want to show the contents of a particular order, you'll be best using controller code to do that:

```
#app/controllers/orders_controller.rb
Class OrdersController < ApplicationController
   def index
      # loop through orders & create instance variable to output
   end
end
```

If you're trying to set `current_order`, you'll probably want to use a [session based model](http://railscasts.com/episodes/119-session-based-model), which will allow you to store the `current_order` object as you require

---

- As a rule of thumb, you should never directly output with Rails - your use of `puts` is basically going to output specific data, which is not in the remit of [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)
- Have you considered changing your `OrderItem` model to just `Item`? It will be much less verbose for when you refer to it -> `@order.items`

Comment: Updating order_id is not the only way. Please refer to the rails guides reference for belongs_to: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference

Comment: Sorry you misunderstood me. I meant from a core perspective - updating the `order_id` in the database is the only way to fundamentally change the association. How you do that programmatically is a different matter

Comment: @RichPeck The `puts` statements are just for debugging. What I'm trying to do in `merge_orders`: if there are two orders with the same `user_id`, assign the `order_id`s of the second order to the original order.

Comment: @RichPeck I think I figured out the problem, but can't figure out how to fix it. See the edit to the question.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, order.reload

Comment: @pixelearth `@order.reload` isn't having the effects I'm expecting. I've tried calling it in a variety of places, but it isn't working.

Comment: See the added info to my answer (the bit about the console)